# non-public selectors in Payload

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, itunes-store, non-public-selectors

My app is rejected due to the reason " use of non-public APIs is not permitted in the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change"

My first version have been approved by app store without any reason and updating next version would lead this result.

I validated the app and found the following :
**iTunes Store operation succeeded with a warning.
The app references non-public selectors in Payload/alootamatar.app/alootamatar:setReuseIdentifier:**

Can anyone pls help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is

a local variable reuseIdentifier is initialized with the Apple defined variable cell.reuseIdentifier.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying delete the DerivedData folder

Comment: I have already deleted all the data from DerivedData folder but issue not resolved.  Also create the fresh project and imported all those classes but not found the solution.